# PHP mail() vs component-based mail sending libraries

Tags: email, swiftmailer

For years I relied on PHP's own mail() function to send an email.
I have just started to experiment with [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) and [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) which allow you to send mail via SMTP.

Does using such a library to send email via SMTP increase your chances of delivering mail successfully compared to PHP's own mail() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those alternatives make life easier, especialy in cases where you want to send UTF-8 content, since that is a very tedious job. First of all the RFC's are not easy reading and the documentation of the php mail() function is incomplete, and there are even some mistakes in it.

Comment: The libraries make job of sending email easier.  I get that.  But do they actually increase your chances of delivering mail successfully?

Comment: No I do not think so. If you're mail is technicaly okay, it should not matter. Then things like sending from a listed/allowed MX server and SPF come into play.